# Rails object not assigning values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm starting in RoR so the next question could be very easy but after some hours I'm ending up in the same forums and can't figure out what happens here.

I have the next model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

  attr_accessor :id, :username, :email, :role, :image, :locale

end
```

This is a very simple user whose information will be brought via API so I don't need more here.

This is my controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def create
  end

  def callback
    user_data = auth_hash.raw_data
    @user = User.new ({
      id: user_data.id,
      username: user_data.username,
      email: user_data.email,
      image: auth_hash.info.image,
      locale: user_data.locale
    })

    fail
    @user.save
    redirect_to '/'
  end

  protected

  def auth_hash
    request.env['xyz']
  end
end
```

The role field is automatically assigned by the migration, I leave it here so you can have a peek:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :email
      t.string :role, default: "user"
      t.string :username
      t.string :image
      t.string :locale

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_index :users, :username, unique: true
  end
end
```

---

DEBUGGING:

There is a `fail` in the controller. When I reach it in my browser, I try to see what the `@user` has, and it shows the following:

```
=> #<User id: nil, email: nil, role: "user", username: nil, image: nil, locale: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

If I do `@user.save` it saves it with nil fields. But if I write `@user.email` it shows my email and also does with the rest of the fields.

---

**EDIT: SOLUTION**
I found my mistake! I was using all the time `@user.email` instead of `@user[:email]` that's why I kept seeing the values when using a dot. It is strange that it didn't work parsing the hash to parameters. So it seems that I can't use a hash to fill the values.
The `@user.new` now looks like this in the controller:

```
@user = User.new
@user[:id] = user_data.id
@user[:username] = user_data.username
@user[:email] = user_data.email
@user[:image] = auth_hash.info.image
@user[:locale] = user_data.locale
```

Comment: Have you tried whitelist parameters, take a look on how to set strong parameters in controllers

Comment: I'm getting the values from a hash, not from Parameters. I've tried converting the hash to params and permitting them but still not working, I get the same behavior

Comment: You should add more info about fail?

Comment: Any suggestion? there is nothing in ```@user.errors```. Also I tried assigning the valuis throgh the user model initializer but same behavior